# Is there any way to change the size of the text box in Messaging?

Tags: sms

I find it hard to edit text messages in the tiny Messaging box. Is there any way to increase the size of it? I'm using CM10 (JB), but the app looks the same as the CM9 (ICS) version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an alternative like Handcent SMS - it has a button to allow full screen editing. Also, you can customize the font size / style to something more suitable from within Handcent.

Comment: Thanks, but I would rather not start downloading separate apps unless there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning your phone sideways (to Landscape format); then you have a larger window. Works for me (Android 6 Moto phone)